How to generate a URL that opens an adroid app?
I'm building an app using kodular and webview component. I need to generate a URL that opens my app when users click in it. Some can give me a easy way to do this? Tutorials and references are greatfull accept. Thank you!
I've tryed to study about deeplinks.
